# Changing div text and CSS when clicking on a div, and reversing the change when you click again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div named `#increase-text-weight` which says "INCREASE TEXT WEIGHT".

Whenever you click on it, the contents of another div named `#post-content` should get `font-weight: 500` and the text of `#increase-text-weight` should be changed to "DECREASE TEXT WEIGHT".

When the div says "DECREASE TEXT WEIGHT" and you click on it, 
`#post-content`
 should get 
`font-weight: 300`
 and the text of 
`#increase-text-weight`
 should be changed to "INCREASE TEXT WEIGHT".

How can I do this?

EDIT:

I had tried doing it by `getElementById` but it didn't work.

Comment: As SO is not intended to be used to write your assignments for you, especially given the lack of effort shown on your part, I'll just guide you to the methods which can do this for you in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/click, http://api.jquery.com/text and http://api.jquery.com/addclass

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, but what about the part where it has to check whether the div says "INCREASE TEXT WEIGHT" or "DECREASE TEXT WEIGHT"?

Comment: That's what the `text()` method I linked to is for

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Also, this is not an assignment.  My school ended one week ago, and I've started trying to learn HTML and CSS, and have just begun learning JS and JQuery.  I tried for around 1 hour until I resorted to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Aha, thank you.

Comment: In that case please edit your attempt in to the question - we're here to help you debug code that's not working, not to write code for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Alright.

Comment: There's another resource that you can find useful stuff about handling the HTML stuff from Javascript, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to do this could be to use and if and else statement.

```
$('#increase-text-weight').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).text() === 'INCREASE TEXT WEIGHT') {
    $('#post-content').addClass('highlight');
    $(this).text('DECREASE TEXT WEIGHT');
  } else {
    $(this).text('INCREASE TEXT WEIGHT');
    $('#post-content').removeClass('highlight'); 
  }
});
```

```js
$('#increase-text-weight').on('click', function() {
 if ($(this).text() === 'INCREASE TEXT WEIGHT') {
    $('#post-content').addClass('highlight');
    $(this).text('DECREASE TEXT WEIGHT');
  } else {
   $(this).text('INCREASE TEXT WEIGHT');
    $('#post-content').removeClass('highlight'); 
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='increase-text-weight'>INCREASE TEXT WEIGHT</div>
<div id='post-content'>Text text and text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning, this is a short way to do this with two clases.

First of all, the id selector $('#test') gets the node element

Then attach a click event listener of to the reference.
After, the selector $(this), makes a reference to selector used in the event attached function, in this case we can say $(this) ==  $("#test").

After the dot, jQuery .toggleClass() method adds or remove a class from the element, also, if you pass a second true or false parameter, the method will add or remove the given class respectively.

So if you chain this two toggleClass() will add the class if it is not there or will remove it if it exist

```js
$("#test").click(function(){ // also can be .on('click',function(){ ... })

    $(this).toggleClass("decreased")
    .toggleClass("increased");

});
```

```css
.decreased {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.increased {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test" class="decreased">Increase my font weight!</div>
```

Comment: This is slick, even though you used my html and css. +1 for explaining as well, unlike the accepted!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using an onClick event on the div you want to be changed. Each time it is clicked we check which class is associated with that `<div>`, and then do the required modifications to that `<div>` based on the class, like updating the text content inside the div with `.text()`, and then switching out the classes like so:

```js
var myDiv = $("#test");

myDiv.click(function() {
  if (myDiv.hasClass("decreased")) {
    myDiv.removeClass("decreased")
      .addClass("increased")
      .text("Decrease my font weight!")
  } else {
    myDiv.removeClass("increased")
      .addClass("decreased")
      .text("Increase my font weight!")
  }
});
```

```css
.decreased {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.increased {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test" class="decreased">Increase my font weight!</div>
```

Although you can easily do this with pure JavaScript like so:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");

myDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (myDiv.className === "decreased") {
    myDiv.classList.remove("decreased");
    myDiv.className = "increased";
    myDiv.textContent = "Decrease my font weight!";
  } else {
    myDiv.classList.remove("increased");
    myDiv.className = "decreased";
    myDiv.textContent = "Increase my font weight!";
  }
});
```